# Android ListView highlight multiple items

Tags: android, listview, selection

I want my ListView to change its background for each selected item (Multi-Selection). I used this code:

```
    <ListView
    ...
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" >
```

This works fine, but it is just possible to select one single item of the list. If I select another one the selection is resetted and the new one changes its background.

Is there an easy and fast way to make it possible to select more than one item at the same time with changing the background of every selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the resource parameter of your ArrayAdapter to android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1

Comment: I am using a SimpleAdapter since I have a custom-layout for the Listitems.